# How to get the value of the first HTML option by default in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.3.1, and I have HTML like this:

```
        <p>
            How many days did your menstrual cycle last?
            <select id="menstrualCycle" onclick="changeFunc('menstrualCycle')">
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
            </select>
        </p>
```

Then I have a JS like this:

```
function changeFunc(select) {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById(select);
    var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;

    if (select == 'monthCycle') {
        monthDays = selectedValue;
        console.log("Month value is: " + monthDays);
    } else if (select == 'menstrualCycle') {
        menstrualDays = selectedValue;
        console.log("Menstrual value is: " + menstrualDays);
    } else if (select == 'lutealPhase') {
        lutealValue = selectedValue;
        console.log("Luteal value is: " + lutealValue);
    }
}
```

The point is that I get the values, by clicking the options or selecting other options. But when the page is open, where my page id is "ovulInfoPicker", by defualt it doesn't get the first values. I want to get the first values by default, without changing the values or pressing the otions.

Comment: Trigger the change event programmatically: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: @FelixKling Can you give a code example, please also note that the default value should be stored in the variable as in the function above.

Comment: `$('#id1, #id2, #id3').trigger('change')` ... You trigger the event which will execute the event handlers without actual user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the change event programmatically: http://api.jquery.com/trigger.

```
$('#id1, #id2, #id3').trigger('change');
```

You trigger the event which will execute the event handlers without actual user interaction.

Answer (score -1):

```
<option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
```

Comment: But, i need to store the default value in my variables, as in the function above.